# Hibernate doesn't save the FOREIGN KEY (OneToMany relationship)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have 2 tables (Expert and PhoneNumber). Each expert can have several numbers. That's why I use @OneToMany in Expert.java, @ManyToOne in PhoneNumber.java

For some reason the expert_id is not saving to the Phone_number table. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Spring Data JPA and PostgreSQL.

**DB Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE Expert (
    expert_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    join_date DATE,
    subscription_expiry_date DATE,
    is_specialist BOOLEAN,
    is_premium BOOLEAN,
    description TEXT,
    photo TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Phone_number (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    expert_id INT,
    phone_number VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (expert_id) REFERENCES Expert(expert_id)
);
```

**Expert.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "expert")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "expert_id")
    private Long expertId;

    // Simple fields

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "expert")
    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    // Getters, setters
```

**PhoneNumber.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone_number")
public class PhoneNumber {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "expert_id", referencedColumnName = "expert_id")
    private Expert expert;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;


    // Getters, setters
```

To comunicate with app I used JpaRepository interface.

**Request**

```
{
    "expertId": 1,
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
        },
        {
            "phoneNumber": "555-555-5555"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "expertId": 1,
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "expert": null,
            "phoneNumber": "555-555-5555"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "expert": null,
            "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
        }
    ]
}
```

**ExpertService.java**

```
@Service
public class ExpertService {

    @Autowired
    private ExpertRepository expertRepository;

    public List<Expert> getExperts() {
        return expertRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Expert> getExpert(Long id) {
        return expertRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdateExperts(List<Expert> experts) {
        expertRepository.saveAll(experts);
    }

    public Expert saveOrUpdateExpert(Expert expert) {
        return expertRepository.save(expert);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please remove the line @Column(name = "phoneNumber") from the Expert entity. This is wrong. There is no such column.

Comment: Thanks, I removed @Column(name = "phoneNumber"). However, that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please add nullable=false to @JoinColumn Also: @JoinColumn(name = "expert_id", referencedColumnName = "expert_id", nullable=false)

Comment: This property generate error because expert_id is null.

org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : pl.diet.expert.jpa.PhoneNumber.expert

Comment: OK. It shows that you have an issue while saving the entities to the database. The relationship to the Expert need to be set prior to saving a new PhoneNumber. You can use the setExpert() method for it. In case of doubts please share the code of service classes in use.

Comment: Service class have a method and repository is clear JpaRepository interface.

`public Expert saveOrUpdateExpert(Expert expert) {
        return expertRepository.save(expert);
    }`

When I was used setExpert() method from PhoneNumber it create database entry twice. 

I would like hibernate to do this saving itself using only annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by editing the method in the ExpertService class

```
public Expert saveOrUpdateExpert(Expert expert) {
    Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = expert.getPhoneNumbers();
    phoneNumbers.forEach(phoneNumber -> {
       phoneNumber.setExpert(expert);
    });
    return expertRepository.save(expert);
}
```

The problem was that Hibernate first tried to write to Phone_number and then to Expert, hence the expert_id on the Phone_number table was null.

Thank you @Mar-Z for your help :)